# Pandas Python: Writing output to specific cells in the CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to write a pandas df to a csv.  However, I need to loop a lot to get my output in chunks.  I want to stack the output vertically in a csv.  So after each iteration, I want to write to a particular set of rows (1:10, then 11:20, etc...) and clear memory so as not to make a giant object.  Is it possible to use df.to_csv to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) accepts a mode argument to append:

```
import numpy as np
# df.shape returns the dimensions in a tuple, the first dimension is the number of rows
df_list = np.array_split(df, df.shape[0]/10)
for d in df_list:
    d.to_csv(csv_path, mode='a')
```

You can use numpy array split to produce a list of your df split into 10 rows each and then write them out or whatever you need to do to save memory

Comment: Oh wow, that's better. I just skimmed the docs and still missed it... sad day.